# Openlayers 5 - How to update the map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have created a map with different layers and a sidemenu with checkboxes to display or not markers. The code I use to do this is good, when I check a checkbox markers are displayed ... but only after I move the map (manual refresh).

I'm searching a way to update the map just after I checked a checkbox otherwise this isn't good at all ... I have found some things to do this by searching on internet but nothing works !

Do you have any idea ?

Here is the code in charge of displaying markers :

```
var disp = function isChecked() {
  var check = document.getElementById("piscine");
  if(check.checked) {
    return marker_style;
  } 
    return null;
}

vectorLayer.setStyle(disp);
```

Comment: Could you explain how you do **move the map (manual refresh)** ? In openlayers you can add a LayerSwitcher instance to your map to switch between layers. https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher

Answer (score 0):

I, after investigating maybe I found a solution:

```
...
var source = vectorLayer.getSource();
source.changed();
```

o

```
source.refresh();
```

Visit: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#refresh

Comment: Hi Fabian, welcome to Stack Overflow! I think there are some formatting errors in your post. It would be helpful if you describe what the code does in your answer too.